# Proof verification: $(M\oplus N)\otimes P \cong (M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification, tensor-products

This is a proposition from Atiyah-Macdonald "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" whose proof has been relegated to the reader. All maps are assumed to be $A$-module homomorphisms unless otherwise stated.

> Proposition 2.14(iii): Let $M,N,P$ be $A$-modules; then, there exists a unique isomorphism $(M\oplus N)\otimes P \to (M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P)$ given by the map $(m,n)\otimes p\mapsto (m\otimes p, n\otimes p)$.

**Plan of proof:** I will show that there exist maps $f$ and $g$:
$$ (M\oplus N)\otimes P \overset{f}{\to} (M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P) \overset{g}{\to} (M\oplus N)\otimes P $$ such that $g\circ f = \text{Id}_{(M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P) }$ and $ g\circ f = \text{Id}_{(M\oplus N)\otimes P}$.

**Proof of proposition:**

Let $\phi: (M\oplus N) \times P \to (M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P)$ be the map defined as:
$$\phi: ((m,n),p)\mapsto (m\otimes p, n\otimes p)$$
It is clear that $\phi$ is $A$-bilinear, and hence the universal property of tensor products gives us the canonical induced map:
$$ \begin{align} f: (M\oplus N) \otimes P &\to (M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P) \\ (m,n)\otimes p &\mapsto (m\otimes p, n\otimes p) \end{align} $$
The next step is to find $g$. Let $\psi_M: M\times P \to (M\oplus N) \otimes P$ and $\psi_N: N\times P \to (M\oplus N) \otimes P$ be defined, as usual, in the obvious ways:
$$ \begin{align} \psi_M: (m,p)&\mapsto (m,0) \otimes p \\ \psi_N: (n,p)&\mapsto (0,n) \otimes p \end{align} $$
Once again, $\psi_M$ and $\psi_N$ are both $A$-bilinear and hence the universal property of tensor products gives us a pair of maps $\tilde{\psi}_M: M\otimes P \to (M\oplus N) \otimes P$ and $\tilde{\psi}_N: N\otimes P \to (M\oplus N) \otimes P$ defined as:
$$ \begin{align} \tilde{\psi}_M: m\otimes p &\mapsto (m,0) \otimes p \\ \tilde{\psi}_N: n\otimes p &\mapsto (0,n) \otimes p \end{align} $$
Therefore, I will define $g: (M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P) \to (M\oplus N)\otimes P$ on basis elements of the form $(m\otimes p, 0)$ and $(0,n\otimes p)$ and extend by linearity.
$$ \begin{align} g: (m\otimes p, 0) &\mapsto \tilde{\psi}_M(m\otimes p) \\ g: (0, n\otimes p) &\mapsto \tilde{\psi}_N(n\otimes p) \end{align} $$
First, we will show that $g$ is well-defined. In other words, let $x,y\in (M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P)$ be such that $x=y$ with representations:
$$ \begin{align} x &= \sum_{i=1}^k (m_i\otimes p_i, 0) + \sum_{i=1}^{\ell} (0,n_i\otimes q_i) \\
y &= \sum_{i=1}^{k'} (m_i'\otimes p_i', 0) + \sum_{i=1}^{\ell'} (0,n_i'\otimes q_i') \end{align} $$ then $g(x) = g(y)$. For simplicity, I will assume that $x = \sum_{i=1}^k (m_i\otimes p_i, 0)$ and $y = \sum_{i=1}^{k'} (m_i'\otimes p_i', 0)$, but the general case is identical, just with more symbols.
$$ \begin{align} \left(\sum_{i=1}^k m_i\otimes p_i, 0\right) &= \sum_{i=1}^k (m_i\otimes p_i, 0) \\ &= x = y \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{k'} (m_i'\otimes p_i', 0) \\ &= \left( \sum_{i=1}^{k'} m_i'\otimes p_i', 0 \right) \end{align} $$
Therefore, $\sum_{i=1}^k m_i\otimes p_i = \sum_{i=1}^{k'} m_i'\otimes p_i'$ and from our definition of $g$ we have that:
$$ \begin{align} g(x) &= \sum_{i=1}^k \tilde{\psi}_M(m_i\otimes p_i) \\
&= \tilde{\psi}_M\left(\sum_{i=1}^k m_i\otimes p_i \right) \tag{Linearity of $\tilde{\psi}_M$} \\ &= \tilde{\psi}_M\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k'} m_i'\otimes p_i' \right) \\ &= \sum_{i=1}^{k'} \tilde{\psi}_M\left(m_i'\otimes p_i' \right) \tag{Linearity of $\tilde{\psi}_M$} \\ &= g(y) \end{align} $$
Therefore, $g$ is well-defined. It is clear that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are both identity maps. Therefore, it suffices to show that $g$ is $A$-linear and we would be done. Let $(m\otimes p,n\otimes q)$ and $(m'\otimes p',n'\otimes q')$ be two basis elements of $(M\otimes P)\oplus (N\otimes P)$.
$$ \begin{align} g((m\otimes p,n\otimes q) + (m'\otimes p',n'\otimes q')) &= g((m\otimes p + m'\otimes p',n\otimes q + n'\otimes q')) \\
&= g((m\otimes p + m'\otimes p',0) + (0,n\otimes q + n'\otimes q')) \\ &= \tilde{\psi}_M(m\otimes p + m'\otimes p') + \tilde{\psi}_N(n\otimes q + n'\otimes q') \\ &= \tilde{\psi}_M(m\otimes p) + \tilde{\psi}_N(n\otimes q) + \tilde{\psi}_M(m'\otimes p') + \tilde{\psi}_N(n'\otimes q') \\ &= g((m\otimes p,n\otimes q)) + g((m'\otimes p',n'\otimes q')) \end{align} $$
$$ \begin{align} g(a(m\otimes p,n\otimes q)) &= g((a(m\otimes p),a(n\otimes q))) \\ &= g((a(m\otimes p), 0) + (0,a(n\otimes q))) \\ &= g((a(m\otimes p), 0)) + g((0,a(n\otimes q))) \\ &= \tilde{\psi}_M(a(m\otimes p)) + \tilde{\psi}_N(a(n\otimes q)) \\ &= a\left( \tilde{\psi}_M(m\otimes p) + \tilde{\psi}_N(n\otimes q) \right)  \\ &= a \left( g((m\otimes p,0)) + g((0,n\otimes q)) \right) \\ &= a g((m\otimes p,n\otimes q))\end{align} $$
This concludes the proof. This was the simplest proof I could come up with. Is this correct? Does anyone know of a shorter proof?

Comment: In general your proof is ok, but bascillay, what you have done is to prove the universal propierty of direct sum, recall that this propierty is even more general $\left(\bigoplus_{i\in\Lambda}M_i\right)\otimes N\cong \bigoplus_{i\in\Lambda}(M_i\otimes N)$.

Comment: The paragraphes showing "$g$ is well-defined" are redundant. In general, if you have maps $\phi: X\rightarrow Z$ and $\psi:Y\rightarrow Z$, then they give a map $\phi \oplus \psi: X \oplus Y \rightarrow Z$ which sends $(x, y)$ to $\phi(x) + \psi(y)$. This is more or less the universal property of direct sum. What you have shown in these paragraphes is actually the well-definedness of $\tilde{\phi_M}$, which already comes from the universal property of tensor product.

Comment: The same applies to the paragraph showing "$g$ is $A$-linear". Everything else is fine.

Comment: @WhatsUp Oh, that's a useful construction. I will remember it. Thanks. Does the fact that $g$ is $A$-linear follow from the fact that $\phi\oplus \psi$ is $A$-linear if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are $A$-linear?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.